# Loadtxt can't find file

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I've pasted the file into every location I can think of and it still won't find it, am I doing something wrong?

```
from numpy import *  
x,y = loadtxt("filename" , unpack=True)
```

always comes up with this error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Did either answer help you?

Comment: Yes, it was just me being silly and forgetting the .txt at the end of the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your file actually needs to have an extension as well:

```
from numpy import *  
x,y = loadtxt("filename.txt" , unpack=True)
```

where `"filename.txt"` gets replaced with the name of the actual file.

Also if your file is not in the folder you are in, you will need to provide the full path and not just the file name. For example, if you have a folder called `data` in the same directory as your script and inside the folder you have your `info.txt` file, you will need to call it as:

```
x,y = loadtxt("./data/info.txt" , unpack=True)
```

Comment: Are you positive that is the problem?  What if it's because they need the directory path as well?